# 2001 vw jetta reverse loss

Tags: vw, transmission, manual-transmission, jetta

I have a 2001 Volkswagen jetta 2.0.  I had it at the shop and the gears all worked as normal.  They put a transmission mount on my car and when I got it back I couldnt get reverse.  First has shifted over and you have to press down and up to get it like you did for reverse all the other gears work as normal without issue.  The same shop tried to say I need a transmission but I know that's not it because the gears were perfect before we put the mount on it.

What could it be?  Looking for something hopefully we can do to fix it because the motor and underbody are great, and its great on fuel.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the linkage adjustment needs attention.

The new mount has put the engine/box back into the original position and time/wear has taken its toll. That combined with possible "sag" in the other mounts means that the linkage is now out of adjustment.

There is a possibility that they may have bent one of the linkages while fitting the new mount when they perhaps jacked up the engine/box to get the new mount into place...

Getting them to admit that....